# ¿Existe alguna forma de que el usuario escriba texto en JavaScript sin ventanas emergentes?

Tags: javascript

Estoy comenzando en JavaScript, se que se puede pedir que el usuario inserte cualquier texto con el código:

```
prompt("Inserta lo que quieras");
```

El problema de esto es que se abre una ventana emergente y me preguntaba si existía alguna manera de hacer lo mismo, pero que se muestre en la propia página, sin ventanas emergentes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para eso existe en HTML la etiqueta `input` específicamente `type="text"`

Ejemplo para pedir el nombre del usuario

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" />
```

La manera mas fácil de referenciar el input desde JavaScript consiste en asignarle un id (en este ejemplo su valor es nombre), aunque existen otras maneras.

Luego desde javascript puedes hacer algo como:

```
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
```

Acá te dejo un ejemplo sencillo ejecutable:

```js
function obtenerNombre() {
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  
  alert(nombre);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nombre" />

<button onclick="obtenerNombre()">Obtener el nombre</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sí, en el propio DOM puedes incrustar un `input` (`text`, `textarea`...) y después capturar el valor que el usuario haya introducido con Javascript. Esto lo puedes lograr mediante una librería tipo jQuery o accediendo directamente al DOM con funciones tipo `document.getElementById`

https://jsfiddle.net/2ywmr89L/1/

En ese simple fiddle (pulsa Run arriba a la izquierda) puedes ver un conciso ejemplo de como utilizar el valor de un usuario introducido en una caja de texto.